# When I run WinSat.exe from the command line, it opens a new terminal window

Tags: terminal, winsat

When I run WinSat.exe, it opens a new terminal window -- and when WinSat terminates, the terminal window is closed, so I don't have time to read the output.

Why is this happening, and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Related: [When running command from Start > Run, the command exits before I can see the results](http://superuser.com/questions/280772/when-running-command-from-start-run-the-command-exits-before-i-can-see-the-res)

Comment: What version of windows are you on? Are you truly running Winstat from inside a terminal? or are you running it from a Run line?

Comment: From the terminal (cmd).

Comment: Is the solution of the question I've linked to not working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering my own question: this doesn't happen if I run WinSAT in a cmd terminal opened with "Run as Administrator".

Presumably, when I run WinSAT in a cmd terminal that wasn't opened as Administrator, it opens a new Administrator terminal, runs WinSAT, then immediately closes the Administrator terminal.

Which really is *helpful*, in the "not helpful" sense of the word, because the only way to figure this out is, well, to figure it out.

Interestingly, WinSAT also doesn't exist as far as Cygwin is concerned; ls and the bash prompt think the file simply doesn't exist. As it has the same permission/security as other files, presumably this too has to do with it being UAC "special".

UAC's such a half-baked implementation.